# Exercise on formal deformations of representations (Etingof 2.24)

Tags: representation-theory

I'm trying to work out a few exercises in Etingof's book on representation theory of associative algebras (http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf)

At the moment I'm looking at Problem 2.24. about formal deformations of representations.

In part (a) one has to show that if $Ext^1(V,V)=0$, then any deformation of $\rho$ is trivial and that I worked out.

My problem is to solve part (b), where one has to show that the converse, in general, doesn't hold.

There is also a hint that says to consider the algebra of dual numbers $A=k\lbrack x\rbrack / (x^2)$, but apart from what I found on Wiki  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number), I have no clue on how this counterexample works, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take $V$ to be the trivial $k[x]/(x^2)$ module $k$. Then $\text{Ext}^1_{k[x]/(x^2)}(V,V)$ (even all $\text{Ext}^n_{k[x]/(x^2)}(V,V)$) can be computed from an explicit projective resolution of $V$ over $k[x]/(x^2)$. Moreover, $\text{End}_k(V)\cong k$ so a deformation of $V$ takes a particularly simple form. Do you want to try to elaborate on that?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: I can't seem to be able to compute Ext$^{1}$ explicitly, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @JackBrand Did you already compute the projective resolution of $V$?

Comment: I didn't, as I don't know what that is. Is there perhaps another way to see that Ext$^{1}$ is nonzero? i.e., using the definitions in Etingof's notes, can we somehow find a nonzero cocycle? Or is this not a good way to approach the problem?